# Create macro dates in loop

Tags: sas

I wrote below part to get the third month from date macro.

```
%let date=2017-01-01; 
%let a_SASdate=%sysfunc(inputn(&date.,yymmdd10.)) ;
%let b=%sysfunc(putn(&a_SASdate.,yymmn6.)) ;
%let et=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&date.,yymmdd10.)),2,s),yymmn6.);
%put  &a_SASdate. &b. &et.;
```

I wrote below code to create macro variable for each date.

```
data new;
do i=1 to 12;
call symput('mon'||put(i,z2.),put(intnx('month',&et.,i),yymmn6.));
a=symget('mon'||put(i,z2.));
output;
end;
run;
```

Expected output

```
i   a
1   201704
2   201705
3   201706
4   201707
5   201708
6   201709
7   201710
8   201711
9   201712
10  201801
11  201801
12  201803
```

But what iam getting is

```
1   251204
2   251205
3   251206
4   251207
5   251208
6   251209
7   251210
8   251211
9   251212
10  251301
11  251302
12  251303
```

What went wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  1st of all, the code does not work. **&dname._&&mon&z.; ** is not valid in middle of do.

Comment: I recreated the question

Answer (score 2):

When &et was resolved to 201703, which is not SAS date, so based on wrong date, intnx('month',&et.,i) gave you wrong results. So you have to convert &et to SAS date first. In addition, you just want define a variable, you don't need multiple macro variable.

```
data new;
do i=1 to 12;
call symput('a',put(intnx('month',input("&et",yymmn6.),i),yymmn6.));
a=symget('a');
output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have year and month for next 12 months from beginning of certain date. I came up with a bit more compact solution:

```
%let date= '1jan17'd; /*Begin date*/

data wanted; 
    do i=1 to 12;
        a=intnx('month',&date.,i); /*increment by single month from begin date*/
        a=put(a, yymmn6.); /*This formats the date to wanted. */
        output;
    end;
run;
```

For more on relevant functions on [IntNx](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/INTNX_Function_examples) and [YYMMxw. Format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/63324/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1k45hxg0vxohqn1ktr8k1tnmrn1.htm)